# Undefined value of variable when exported - react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access a variable inside a class in another file.

Here is my code:

Time.js

```
class Time extends Component{
    static _hrInput = ''
    static _minInput = ''
    static _check = false 

    hrInput(newValue) {
        this._hrInput = newValue
    }

    minInput(newValue) {
        this._minInput = newValue
    }

    checkInput(newValue) {
        this._check = newValue
    }

    getValues() {
        return [this._hrInput, this._minInput, this._check]
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <form className="Time-form">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="00" 
                    value={this._hrInput} 
                    name='hour' 
                    className='Time-input-hr'
                    onChange={(e) => this.hrInput(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label className="space">
                    <text>:</text>
                </label>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="00" 
                    value={this._minInput} 
                    name='minute' 
                    className='Time-input-min'
                    onChange={(e) => this.minInput(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label className="am-pm-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.checkInput(!this._check)}
                    />
                    <span className="am">AM</span>
                    <span className="pm">PM</span>
                </label>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Time 

const store = new Time()

export {store}
```

NewLocalStorage.js

```
function NewLocalStorage() {
    const time = () => {
        var list = store.getValues()
        console.log(list)
    }

    time()
}

export default NewLocalStorage;
```

When I try to print out the variables _hrInput, _minInput, and _check, it prints out undefined instead of updated versions of the variables. Additionally, I have tried using state however they don't return the updated versions of the variables, only the values that are initially defined.

I'm not really sure what to do.

Comment: If I may, what is it that you are trying to achieve by calling a component as a class?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not quite sure. I'm new to react and I would say classes in general. Would using a function be better?

Comment: Did you read the getting started docs? Thats not how you use the class as a component, you suppose to invoke React.createElement (<Test/>)

Comment: Ohh, I see. So changing it to a function is the correct way?